# f.time_field with 24 hour clock - Rails Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a little Rails app that I need to use the 24-hour clock for inputting times.  Right now, I've got:

```
  <div class=".col-md-7">
    <%= f.label :backinservice %><br>
    <%= f.time_field :backinservice %>
  </div>
```

Which gives an AM/PM option.  When I input a time like 18:56, it automagically converts it to 06:56 PM.  Normally that would be totally ok, just not in this app.

I also tried:

```
  <div class=".col-md-7">
    <%= f.label :recieved %><br>
    <%= f.time_field :recieved, :format=>"%H:%M" %>
  </div>
```

But that doesn't work either.

Is there a `:format` option that allows for straight use of the 24-hour clock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the format using `value` key.

```
<div class=".col-md-7">
  <%= f.label :recieved %><br>
  <%=
    f.time_field :recieved,
      value: "%H:%M",
      min: 'hh:mm:ss',
      max: 'hh:mm:ss'
  %>
</div>
```

The [doc](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-time_field) says:

> The default value is generated by trying to call strftime with “%T.%L” on the objects's value. **It is still possible to override that by passing the “value” option**.

Comment: Used the `, value: "%H:%M"` key you suggested, but my application seems to still change 1900 to 0700 - and I cannot enter any hour greater than 20:00

Comment: @PSCampbell You need to mention the min and max for that. Please try now. But it may not work in old browsers, because this helper creates HTML 5 time tag.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following to get this to work for me:

```
<%=
    f.time_field :my_time_field,
    value: f.object.my_time_field.strftime("%H:%M")
  %>
```

Found this out by looking at the [definition](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9f44aa08636dfbba9261f4350ec14684425c4b7b/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1067) of time_field, that is only creating a new instance of `Tags::TimeField.new`

In turn `Tags::TimeField.new` only does one thing which is to [define the format](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9f44aa08636dfbba9261f4350ec14684425c4b7b/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/time_field.rb).